# Can't add android platform in cordova on Mac

Tags: android, cordova

I'm not sure what step I've missed, but I cannot get Cordova to add the android platform to my sample project.

This what I am getting from Terminal:

```
:hello2 my-username$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/Users/my-username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                      ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed,     and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

And this is what I have in my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/my-username/Documents/Development/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/my-username/Documents/Development/sdk/tools
```

My /Development directory is set up like this:

/eclipse

/hello2

/sdk

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you run the android sdk manager and download api 19?

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

Check your ant installation is working ok with "ant -version".

Add the following to your bash profile (you may have ant installed somewhere else, so check/find your path in Finder first):

export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/share/ant/bin"

Reboot to apply the new shell paths.

Check your path output in your shell with: "echo $PATH" to ensure it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't define the path for android-sdk. Make sure you have installed latest updated version of android-sdk.

Path for android-sdk:
    -ANDROID_HOME (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools)